# How to efficiently filter items in a list based on a property in Python?

Tags: python, list, filter

I'm working on a Python script where I need to filter a list of objects based on a property that the objects have. I'm currently using a list comprehension to do this, but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way, both in terms of performance and readability, especially when the list is very large.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, category):
        self.name = name
        self.category = category

items = [
    Item("apple", "fruit"),
    Item("cucumber", "vegetable"),
    Item("banana", "fruit"),
    Item("spinach", "vegetable")
]

# Filter to get only the fruits
fruits = [item for item in items if item.category == "fruit"]
print([f.name for f in fruits])  # Output: ['apple', 'banana']
```

I've looked into using the filter() function, as well as generator expressions, but I'm not sure if these would offer any performance benefits or if there are other more Pythonic ways of doing this.

Specifically, I'd like to know:

1. What is the most efficient way to filter a list with thousands of items by a property?
2. Does the method change if the property to filter by is nested deeper in the object (e.g., item.details.category)?

Could someone explain if list comprehensions are the best choice here or if there are better alternatives that I should consider?

Thanks!

Comment: depends if you need the whole filtered list, or just the elements 1-by-1, `filter(lambda e: e.category == "fruit", items)` is an iterator and can be used in a `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

If you want to optimize for efficient querying you can store items as a dict of lists with categories as keys:

```
items_of_category = {}
for item in items:
    items_of_category.setdefault(item.category, []).append(item)
```

so that you can obtain a list of items filtered by a specific category in a constant time complexity:

```
fruits = items_of_category['fruit']
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have a dictionary that's common to all Item instances where categories are mapped to a list of names. In that way you don't need a list comprehension

Something like this:

```
class Item:
    dCat = dict()
    def __init__(self, name, category):
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        Item.dCat.setdefault(category, []).append(name)


Item("apple", "fruit")
Item("cucumber", "vegetable")
Item("banana", "fruit")
Item("spinach", "vegetable")

print(*Item.dCat.get("fruit", []), sep="\n")
```

**Output:**

```
apple
banana
```

Answer (score -1):

Use filter and lambda map function to improve performance.

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, category):
        self.name = name
        self.category = category

items = [
 Item("apple", "fruit"),
 Item("cucumber", "vegetable"),
 Item("banana", "fruit"),
 Item("spinach", "vegetable")
]

fruits= list(filter(lambda item: item.category=="fruit", items))

print(list(map(lambda x:x.name, fruits)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).